# Could I have damaged hard driver connector when replacing HDD and how can I test?

Tags: hard-drive, connector

Hi I replaced the HDD with an SSD on a HP Pavilion 15-aw065sa. It's not meant to be upgraded by a consumer, but it's a long story and I didn't have a choice! Anyway I managed to take the thing apart with a spudger and got everything working and copied the image of the old OS over to it. However I accidentally yanked the HDD connector to motherboard. It's like a ribbon which clips into place by a clip on the board. Is there any way to test the connector or detect potential damage that might not be apparent in the general operation of the laptop, which seems fine.

Comment: You inspect the ribbon for tears, if there are no tears, you check if the drive its connected to can be detected.

Comment: Is this ribbon likely to be the power supply - it's not the main cable that connects into the drive. The drive seems fine, I've been using it for most of today. Plus if there's a test I can do with opening up the case again that would be ideal, it's really difficult and I'm concerned I'll do more harm than good.

Comment: Of course its connected to the PSU.  The HDD requires power in order to operate.

Comment: Your Service guide...  http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05122652

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, hard to answer thoroughly to the problem, but here is some info to the topic.

The HDD/SSD adapter probably is quite regular ab. 1 2/3" long SATA adapter with a flat ribbon with 12 flat pins on the m/b end, taking care both of signal and power, and is connected to the m/b with a tiny flat flip-clip. For a few weeks ago I did struggle quite a time with one to get it properly seated/connected to the m/b clip, and finally succeeding. So, the problem may also be on this bad connection. But, how to test the ribbon, I do not have any other suggestion than several times retrying the seating/connecting, or, maybe there is somewhere available a test plug for these 12 flat pins to be checked/measured somehow "off-line".

Edit: OK, thanks @Moab for the Service Guide link. Didn't know there may be on some models also an option for an internal SSD stick (part no 13, page 16-17, removal, page 33), which wasn't at all mentioned on the data sheet of this particular model ... But, anyway I think on this topic it's in question a HDD/SSD replacement to the HDD adapter.